# How to manage groups in SignalR core? (joining/leaving from all)

Tags: .net-core, signalr

I have some questions about SignalR.

1. An app scenario: An user can join/leave to many groups (NxN). But
   those groups can be changed with a new request. So, how to remove an
   user from all joined groups and add him to new list of groups? (Such
   as: in first request i join A,B,C groups and with second request i
   want to be in only groupS X,Z -i'm not listening a,b,c groups anymore-).
2. How to check a group name if it's already exists?
3. How to remove a group if it has no users/members in it? (garbage collector)

Hope someone helps me here!
(Signalr core: 2.2)

Answer (score 0):

SignalR don't provide you the list of users that are in groups, how many groups there are and their names. So the logic that you need to implement is create for example a `Dictionary` so you can add there the name of your group and the users that are associated to that group. So when a request comes to change user from group A to group B you can do:

- Lookup in what groups the user is.
- Remove the user from the group.
- Create the new group and add it to your Dictionary.
- Add the user to the new group.

I believe this is a good aproach if you have one SignalR app/host because if you will have many instances of your signalR app, you can not access to the `Dictionary` to see if there is a user in some group in some other instance.

Comment: I'll have too many groups and users so this could impact performance in one server. I couldn't find a working sample in entire web for it. I think it's most common problem for everyone who plays with SignalR.

Comment: I'll wait for more scalable solution for this problem. Thanks for your answer!